# WordPress Firebase notification to Android App

Tags: android, wordpress, firebase, firebase-notifications

I have searched and searched, but I simply cannot find the answer.

I want to send a notification to **ALL** of my **Android App users** when a new **blog** is posted on my **WordPress** site (I do not need the users to sign up to the site).

I have been able to send notification from the Firebase console to all App users, but do not know how to achieve this automatically from WordPress.

Please guide me. I think many people are looking for a solution which is free/works.

Comment: i am in exact the same situation as you but im looking to also send push notifications to iOS.
i found these two wordpress plugins:
1) https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-push-notification/
2) https://wordpress.org/plugins/push-notifications-for-wp/
but they are not working on iOS and i get mixed status on android.
As another solution is something like this:
https://zapier.com/zapbook/firebase/wordpress/
but you need some kind of firebase database watcher to send pushes when zapier adds the posts entries in your database.
please let me know if you found any solution in the meantime

Comment: Hey, thank you -  I have a solution for ANDROID only though:  after a lot of trials and error, I found one that works (finally).  It does involve you having to modify code according to your needs though.  There is a nice tutorial and download link:  https://www.warmbeer.io/2017/03/01/going-wild-with-wordpress-notifications/

Comment: any recent update on this? i am also looking for similar feature. Thanks

Comment: Any update on this ? i am having same situation now